# Algorithm to always sum sliders to 100% failing due to zeroes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, algorithm

This is (supposed to be) a function which makes sure that the the sum of a number of slider's values **always** adds up to `globalTotal`.

A slider value can be changed manually by the user to `changer.value` and then when applying this function to the values of the **other** sliders, it can determine their new or `endVal`.

It takes the `startVal` of the slider which needs changing and the original value of the slider that changed `changerStartVal` and can determine the new value others by weighting.

The problem and my question is. Sometimes `remainingStartVals` can be *zero* (when the slider changing gets moved all the way to maximum) or `startVal` can be *zero* (when the slider changing is moved to zero and then another slider is moved). When this happens I get a divide-by-zero or a multiply-by-zero respectively. Both of which are bad and lead to incorrect results. Is there an easy way to fix this?

```
func calcNewVal(startVal: Float, changerStartVal: Float) -> Float {

    let remainingStartVals = globalTotal - changerStartVal

    let remainingNewVals = globalTotal - changer.value

    let endVal = ((startVal * (100 / remainingStartVals)) / 100) * remainingNewVals

    return endVal

}
```

Comment: You should fix the algorithm. A proper algorithm won't lead you to a cases of division by zero. By the way, what does '100' mean? Not only both '100' are useless here, their origin is a mystery.

Comment: @MaxPevsner thanks for the great tip. I'm trying to fix the algorithm. That's why I'm here. Far from the '100' being useless. They get the weighting of the values of what they were to what they need to be. It's nothing to do with percent. And they don't cancel each other out.

Comment: Hey @Sean, are you updating the globalTotal? Also if you have multiple slider as you said do you apply this to each with the same value of changerStartVal?

Comment: Hey @M090009 no globalTotal is a constant. And yes, i have multiple different slider values, and yes I do apply this to each to determine what its new value should be.

globalTotal is a constant because all the sliders are supposed to add to it no matter what happens.

Comment: @Sean I'm afraid I don't quite understand the requirements. Let's say you have 3 sliders. Their total should be 99. At the beginning all are set to 33. Then the user picks one and changes it's value to 66. What will happen to the other two? How will be the remainder divided between them? Does any of them have any priority?

Comment: @MaxPevsner good point, Sean you've mentioned a "can determine the new value others by weighting" do you mean that each slide has a weight to it?

Comment: Ok cool. So that would work out [as follows.](http://file.5ep4r0.com/MSlZrVZ.png)

Comment: @MaxPevsner [more detail here](http://file.5ep4r0.com/Hzuh4ql.png) it's not the simplest algo but it works! Came up with it half asleep after days of trying :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a mathematical problem, not a problem related to Swift or any specific programming language so I'll answer with mathematical formulas and explanations rather than code snippets.

I don't really understand your algorithm either. For example in this line:

```
let endVal = ((startVal * (100 / remainingStartVals)) / 100) * remainingNewVals
```

you first multiply by 100 and then divide by 100, so you could just leave all these 100 factors out in the first place!

---

However, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve and the problem is that there *is* no generic solution. Before writing an algorithm you have to define *exactly* how you want it to behave, **including all edge cases**.

Let's define:

- ***v<sub>i</sub>*** as the value of the ***i***-th slider and
- ***Δ<sub>i</sub>*** as the change of the ***i***-th slider's value

Then you have to think of the following cases:

---

#### Case 1:

> ***0 < v<sub>i</sub> ≤ 1*** for all sliders (other than the one you changed)

This is probably the common case you were thinking about. In this case you want to adjust the values of your unchanged sliders so that their total change is equal to the change ***Δ<sub>changed</sub>*** of the slider you changed. In other words:

***∑<sub>i</sub> Δ<sub>i</sub> = 0***

If you have 3 sliders this reduces to:

- ***Δ<sub>1</sub> + Δ<sub>2</sub> + Δ<sub>3</sub> = 0***

And if the slider that changed is the one with ***i = 1*** then this requirement would read:

- ***Δ<sub>1</sub> = – (Δ<sub>2</sub> + Δ<sub>3</sub>)***

You want the sliders to adjust proportionally which means that this change ***Δ<sub>1</sub>*** should not be distributed equally on the other sliders but depending on their current value:

- ***Δ<sub>2</sub> = – w<sub>2</sub> * Δ<sub>1</sub>***
- ***Δ<sub>3</sub> = – w<sub>3</sub> * Δ<sub>1</sub>***

The normed weight factors are

- ***w<sub>2</sub> = v<sub>2</sub> / (v<sub>2</sub> + v<sub>3</sub>)***
- ***w<sub>3</sub> = v<sub>3</sub> / (v<sub>2</sub> + v<sub>3</sub>)***

Thus we get:

- ***Δ<sub>2</sub> = – v<sub>2</sub> / (v<sub>2</sub> + v<sub>3</sub>) * Δ<sub>1</sub>***
- ***Δ<sub>3</sub> = – v<sub>3</sub> / (v<sub>2</sub> + v<sub>3</sub>) * Δ<sub>1</sub>***

So these are the formulas to applied for this particular case.

However, there are quite a few other cases that don't work with this approach:

---

#### Case 2:

> ***v<sub>i</sub> = 0*** for at least one, but not all of the sliders (other than the one you changed)

In this case the approach from *case 1* would still work (plus it would be the logical thing to do). However, a slider's value would never change if it's zero. All of the change will be distributed over the sliders with a value > 0.

---

#### Case 3:

> ***v<sub>i</sub> = 0*** for all sliders (other than the one you changed)

In this case the proportional change doesn't work because there is simply no information how to distribute the change over the sliders. They're all zero! This is actually your zero division problem: In the case where we have 3 sliders and the slider 1 changes we'll get

***v<sub>2</sub> + v<sub>3</sub> = 0***

This is only another manifestation of the fact that the weight factors ***w<sub>i</sub>*** are simply undefined. Thus, you'll have to manually define what will happen in this case.

The most plausible thing to do in this case is to distribute the change *evenly* over all sliders:

***Δ<sub>i</sub> = – (1 / n) * Δ<sub>1</sub>***

where ***n*** is the *number of sliders* (excluding the one that was changed!). With this logic, every slider gets "the same share" of the change.

---

Now that we're clear with our algorithm you can implement these cases in code. Here some pseudo code as an example:

```
if sum(valuesOfAllSlidersOtherThanTheSliderThatChanged) == 0 {
    for allUnchangedSliders {
        // distribute change evenly over the sliders
        Δi = – (1 / n) * Δ_changedSlider
    }
}
else {
    for allUnchangedSliders {
        // use weight factor to change proportionally
        Δi = – v_i / ∑(v_i) * Δ_changedSlider
    }
}
```

Please be aware that you *must* cache the values of the current state of your sliders at the beginning ***or*** (even better) first compute all the changes and then apply all the changes in a batch. Otherwise you will use a value ***v<sub>2</sub>'*** that you just computed for determining the value ***v<sub>3</sub>'*** which will obviously result in incorrect values.

Comment: Helluva answer. Will implement and feed back. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Sean the simplest adjustment that I could think of here is to check if the `remainingStartVals` is not **0** that means that there are weights assigned to the other sliders and also check if a single slider had a weight to begin with which means its `startVal` shouldn't be equal to **0**

```
func calcNewVal(startVal: Float, changerStartVal: Float) -> Float{
var endVal = 0
let remainingStartVals = globalTotal - changerStartVal
if remainingStartVals != 0 || startVal != 0{
    let remainingNewVals = globalTotal - changer.value
    endVal = ((startVal * (100 / remainingStartVals)) / 100) * remainingNewVals
}
return endVal
```

}